# Is it possible to share user group (with itself) using Apex Sharing?

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

Objective is to share a 'User Group' with itself. Following code works fine to share a 'User' with a 'User Group', but not for sharing 'User Group'.

```
  UserShare groupShr = new UserShare();
  groupShr.UserId = toShareId;//works for ID of User, not for ID of User Group
  groupShr.UserOrGroupId = spaceGroupId;
  groupShr.UserAccessLevel = 'Read';
  groupShrList.add(groupShr);

  insert groupShrList;
```

Exception thrown if above code tries to share user group is
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, User ID: id value of incorrect type: 00GF0000004ucwlMAA: [UserId]: Trigger.TriggerName: line 30, column 1

Is it possible to share user group?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_usershare.htm) clearly states that the `userId` has to be the Id of the user being shared. So you cannot set it to the groupId.

The other work around is: you get the users in the group, then itereate thru all the users and then share the records.

Comment: Yes, User ID has to be ID of the User & not of the group. That's why the question- is it even possible to share user group?